# My derailleur doesn't go from gear 1 to gear 2 by itself but the rest does

Tags: derailleur-rear

The derailleur doesn't go from gear 1 to gear 2 by itself so I have to manually push it, it works perfectly fine shifting from 2 to 7 but when I try to change the gear to 8, it stays on 7

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles SE. Did you do any maintenance / swapping of parts before the shifting went off or did this pop up while riding? If it is a new rear derailleur (or you did some adjustments before), you might have to go to the full [indexing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkZxPIZ1ngY&t=2s) process but it might also be a defective cable or loose screw, to me this sounds like the cable is missing some tension but I could be wrong. Turn the RD's barrel adjuster a 1/4 turn anticlockwise and see if it has any effect - if it is a tension issue, the 7-8 shift should work better....

Comment: What happens when you shift from 1 straight to 3? (I.e., two clicks regardless of whether the first one gets you to gear 2.)

Comment: Has the bike recently been in a crash? A bent [derailleur hanger](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/workshop/derailleur-hangers/) may cause this behavior. They're pretty soft and easy to bend - just having the bike fall over wrong may be enough to get it out of adjustment.

Comment: This is the derailleur the bike has always come with, it hadn't been in a crash when it stopped working. I just changed gears quickly which I know isn't a good thing to do. Ever since I did that, the problem started. When it's on gear 1, I can put the shifter all the way to 8 and it won't budge. it shifts to 1 just doesn't go out of 1